# What is this symbol ? (Visual Studio 2015, next to line numbers)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I do not focus on keyboard when typing. So sometimes, unknown shortcuts got executed (then I end up learning new features from the ide).

This is the first time I found this symbol in VS 2015. I am used to "most" symbols in that IDE but this is totally new for me:

[image]

It's not a bookmark, not a breakpoint but what?

I do not know at all which key combinations I have already pressed to get it shown.

Symbol in question is the red squared one (included both in image just to note it's not a bookmark).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to add tasks to your project (I use it in vs 2019 now), it is
usually done by the following steps:

- create a commented line that contains your task description.
- Put the cursor in that line.
- Choose from menu: **Edit > bookmarks > Add to task list**.

you can view the task list by choosing from the menu; **View > Task list**.
See the images in these links [Link 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0crsYg3mDQnZd8vU4A1DYKlg8YuxieM/view?usp=sharing) [Link 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jw2mmIFEeKqBM1JooBLK1MBAYjTsNfv1/view?usp=sharing) [Link 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BoRtQkUiQ8jfKiKoFsAlAqj9NP0poUBG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks, @AkSalim!